# Way to determine eigenvalues from 3. degree characteristic equation?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I have derived the following characteristic equation for a matrix

$$a^3 - 3a^2 - a + 3 = 0$$ where $a = \lambda$.

I know that it's possible to find the roots (eigenvalues) by factorization, but I find this to be especially difficult with cubic equations and was wondering if there perhaps is an easier way to solve the problem.

Comment: Merely by observation you can see that a=1 satisfies the cubic.

Comment: By inspection, 1 being a root, deflate your polynomial to get a quadratic. But you also could find by inspection that -1 and +3 are also solutions (3 being particularly obvious)..

Comment: I see, what about a problem where that is not immediately obvious

Comment: Search Wikipedia for cubic equations. In particular, you will find the famous formulas by Cardano.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici I cannot think of a single instance where it is useful to express eigenvalues with Cardanos formulas.

Comment: @Phira. I totally agree with you. The OP was asking for solving a cubic.

Comment: When you compute the characteristic equation, it may be already in factored form; for example, if the matrix in block diagonal. But there is no shortcut for a general matrix.

Comment: If you want to avoid the cubic by all means, you can resort to the iterative power method. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_iteration. But that's much more work than the closed formulas :(

Answer (score 3):

Note that your cubic characteristic polynomial is always monic. If your matrix has integer coefficients, then ALL rational roots are (positive or negative) divisors of the constant term.

Therefore, the method that works in more than 90% of $3\times3$-exercise problems is: Try out the divisors starting with the small ones, split off the linear factor, solve the quadratic equation.

If your cubic polynomial with integer coefficients does NOT have rational solutions, the reasonable way to go is usually a numeric solution.

So, if it is an exam question and you have checked all divisors and you have not found a rational root, I recommend to search for the error in the calculation of the characteristic polynomial.

Answer (score 0):

$$a^3 - 3a^2 - a + 3 = (a+1)(a-1)(a-3)$$

Answer (score 0):

Besides using a computer algebra system, if the characteristic equation comes from a matrix in a textbook, there is a very high likelihood that it has a rational root (and probably an integer).  You may find the rational root theorem useful if you need to do this by hand.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_root_theorem

In this case, the only things to check are $\pm 1$ and $\pm 3$ and you win on 3 of the 4, so it is pretty good.

Answer (score 0):

$$a^3 - 3a^2 - a + 3 = 0$$
$$a^3-a-(3a^2-3)=0$$
$$a(a^2-1)-3(a^2-1)=0$$
$$(a^2-1)(a-3)=0$$
$$(a^2-1^2)(a-3)$$
$$(a-1)(a+1)(a-3)=0$$

Answer (score 0):

Notice that $-1$ is a root for the polynomial $P(x)=x^3-3x^2-x+3$, therefore $x+1$ divides$P(x)$ so $P(x)=(x+1)Q(x)$ with $deg(Q)=2$ use the euclideanto determine it .

Answer (score -1):

Personally, I hate dealing with polynomial equations to the third power. My escape from those is the following. Once you got a $3\times 3$ matrix, reduce it to a triangular matrix. According to the theorem from the book: "The eigenvalues of a triangular matrix are the entries on its main diagonal". For example, if the main diagonal entries in your triangular matrix are $1$, $3$, $4$, then the polynomial equation would be $(1-a)(3-a)(4-a)$. Thus your eigenvalues would be $1$, $3$ and $4$ respectively. Here we go, no synthetic division.